# Instagram security and two factor authentication

Tags: instagram

Instagram increases its security day by day. Whenever someone logs in to an account from another device, an unusual login attempt comes to screen and the person gets notification about it. How does Instagram get to know about it? Do they trace the IP address or some other thing? If a user (ethical hacker maybe) wants to login without  notifying the person when he knows the username and password by skipping 2FA, how does he do that?

Answer (score 1):

Normally such websites keep track of browser cookies from their they identify if the device is same or different. in case of browser 2FA can be bypassed by cookies stealing but in case of instagram they might be tracking IP and device address when a request is made. There are different ways to bypass 2FA like the one i mentioned in case of browser.

Comment: So can we capture cookies on android. Because I can do the same on browsers but never tried for android

Comment: Yes you can. Different pen-testing tools are available

Comment: For eg? Which I can use for the same

Comment: you can try santoku linux distribution
It has all types of tools for mobile devices

Answer (score -1):

I think instagram uses fingerprints from the web browser, ip and os from the owner of the account, as soon as someone tries to log in and this fingerprints does not match the original one instagram will send notification, if ethical hacker tries to log in I think he needs to know the exact fingerprints and/or use something similiar or spoof the SMS code which the owner of the instagram account will get.

Comment: I don't think that fingerprint matters. Most of earlier phones disney have fingerprint @BaiHui